# Handling free period within active Apple / Google Play subscription?

Tags: google-play, app-store, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

Our product owner wants to grant users a month's free subscription in exchange for inviting another user. We handle subscriptions using App Store / Google Play. Is there any way to give a user a discount for one whole month within an active subscription? Another idea is just to postpone the next payment by one month. I can't find suitable solutions to our case in Google / Apple documentation.

Any help / suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- With Google, you can use the [defer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#defer) to postpone the next payment
- With Apple, you can provide an [offer code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_offer_codes_in_your_app) to offer a free period to your user

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's the only option for google play. Google has promo codes but it is not possible to extend an active subscription https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/promo